# Using gmatch captures to index a table

Tags: string, lua, pattern-matching, openwrt

I want to get the index and x values. From gmatch function, i is the character so i failed this code. I want to get the values and indexes. Is there any solution from this?

```
val[1] = 24
fx = {}

for i, x in response_body[1]:gmatch([["(%w+)lId"%s*:%s*(%d+)]]) do
fc[i] = x
print(x)
end
/* x prints 14
            18
            23 */

if (val[1] ~= fc[1] and val[1] ~= fc[2] and val[1] ~= fc[3] ) then
val[1] = fc[1]

else
val[1] = val[1]
end
```

Comment: `fc[i] = tonumber(x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string.gmatch` returns strings. So `i` and `x` are both strings in your code, given that you have a match of course.

`f[1]` is not the same as `f["1"]`.

So in your code `fc[1]` and so on are `nil` values and hence cannot equal `24`

You can use `tonumber` to convert a `string` to a `number` value. But keep in mind that converting an alphanumeric character as matched by `%w` is not necessarily convertible to a number. You have to avoid using nil as a table index or you will get an error.